# This is a node db problem. I include the user model but it is not included in the result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

What's wrong with the api or router? I definitely included the user model Why is no user information included? Below is the api logic for loading an existing post.

Since the author information is also required, the user model information is included using the include syntax below.

User information is not printed.
What is the reason?

git
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/node_bird_22

api code

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => { // GET /api/posts
    try {
        const posts = await db.Post.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: db.User,
                attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
            }],
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']], // DESC는 내림차순, ASC는 오름차순
        });
        console.log("posts : ", posts);

        res.json(posts);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        next(e);
    }
});
```

model

```
// back\models\post.js

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Post = sequelize.define('Post', { // 테이블명은 posts
        content: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT, // 매우 긴 글
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        charset: 'utf8mb4', //  한글+이모티콘
        collate: 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    });

    Post.associate = (db) => {
        db.Post.belongsTo(db.User); // 테이블에 UserId 컬럼이 생겨요
        db.Post.hasMany(db.Comment);
        db.Post.hasMany(db.Image);

        // 릴레이션 관계 추가
        db.Post.belongsTo(db.Post, { as: 'Retweet' }); // RetweetId 컬럼 생성
        db.Post.belongsToMany(db.Hashtag, { through: 'PostHashtag' });
        db.Post.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'Like', as: 'Likers' });
    };

    return Post;

};
```

result

```
  Post {
    dataValues:
     { id: 21,
       content: 'write test',
       createdAt: 2019-11-07T09:43:00.000Z,
       updatedAt: 2019-11-07T09:43:00.000Z,
       UserId: 1,
       RetweetId: null,
       User: [User] },
    _previousDataValues:
     { id: 21,
       content: 'write test',
       createdAt: 2019-11-07T09:43:00.000Z,
       updatedAt: 2019-11-07T09:43:00.000Z,
       UserId: 1,
       RetweetId: null,
       User: [User] },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: true,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: false,
       underscored: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       charset: 'utf8mb4',
       collate: 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       hooks: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       include: [Array],
       includeNames: [Array],
       includeMap: [Object],
       includeValidated: true,
       attributes: [Array],
       raw: true },
    isNewRecord: false,
    User:
     User {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       isNewRecord: false } } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const where = {};
let options = { where };

options.include = [
    {
        model: db.User,
        attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
    },
];
options.order = [['createdAt', 'DESC']];

const posts = await db.Post.findAll(options);
```

Try this it will help

Comment: I solved the problem using the code you provided. I've been thinking about this since yesterday. Thanks !